# Put-Call Parity Arbitrage Exploitation for Binary-Asset-or-Nothing Options

Tags: exotics, binary-options, put-call-parity

Is the Put-Call-Parity valid for binary (asset-or-nothing) options? If not, is there another formula for such exotic options?

I know that for regular options, there are arbitrage opportunities when the put-call-parity does not hold.

---

Please note that I am very new to learning finance and I am not looking for overly complex answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the call version pays
$$
I_{S_T > K } S_T
$$
the put version pays
$$
-I_{S_T < K } S_T
$$

Subtract to get a pay-off
$$
S_T.
$$
(ignoring the probability zero event of $S_T=K.$)

So the prices subtract to give $S_0.$

Comment: Is $$I_{S_T}$$ the indicator function?

Comment: I understand how to price the options. Could you please clarify how your discussion is related to the Put-Call Parity.

Comment: it shows that the call minus the put price is the stock price regardless of model. Is this not what you want?

Comment: @Ryan What Mark Joshi stated, he was trying to show you put-call parity works for all options. The parity is independent and can be applied to all kind of options. The version that you see in a text-book is simply a generalized version.